# Command-line CD player for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, command-line, media-player, optical-media

I'm looking for a decent open-source command-line CD player for Linux preferably available in the Debian repos. I've tried the following options:

- `mpv`, but it can't select tracks
- `mplayer`, but it buffers every few seconds
- Audacious, but it crashes when I try to play a CD and it has a GUI
- VLC, which actually works (except for a buffering bug), but it has a GUI (and apparently also a `ncurses` interface)

Comment: VLC comes with `cvlc` the command line interface.

Comment: @glennjackman: But with `cvlc` I can't control anything, unlike with `rvlc` or `nvlc`, which I hadn't heard of until I looked up `cvlc`, could you post that as an answer?

Comment: why don't just rip the CD into mp3, aac or whatever? It'll be more efficient and easier to play

Comment: Not tried myself, but there's e.g. [cdcd](http://libcdaudio.sourceforge.net/) (package `cdcd`) and [cdtool](http://hinterhof.net/cdtool/) (package name `cdtool`). Both sound like worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

cdtool text-based audio CD player can be installed from the default repositories in all currently supported versions of Debian.

```
cdtool – text-based audio CD player and CD-ROM control commands
```

```
cdtool contains cdplay, cdeject, cdstop, cdpause, and several other
programs for playing audio CDs and controlling a CD-ROM drive from
the command line and in a quick and scriptable way.

cdown reads track info and queries a CDDB database for info on
the current CD. cdctrl is a command line utility for controlling a
CD-ROM drive interactively and from scripts. cdir keeps track of the
contents of different CDs using a workman-compatible database.
```